# How to keep one single column as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have dataframe with 20 columns and one index.

Its shape is something like (100, 20).

I want to slice the 3rd column from this dataframe, but want to keep the result as a dataframe of (100,1).

1. If I do a `v = df['col3']`, I get a Series (which I do not want)
2. If I do a `v =df[df['col3']!=0]` and then `v.drop(label=[list of 19 columns], axis = 1)` --- I get what I want [that is a df(100,1)] but I have to

(a) write an unnecessary != condition ( which I want to avoid) and

(b) I have to write a long list of 19 column names.

There should be a better and cleaner way of doing what I wan to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another handy trick is `to_frame()`

```
df['col3'].to_frame()
```

Comment: Nice. Clearer in the code than the hackish-looking `reset_index()`.

Answer (score 3):

> If I do a `v = df['col3']`, I get a Series (which I do not want)

If you use `df[cols]`, where `cols` is a list, you'll get a DataFrame (not a Series). This includes the case where it is a list consisting of a single item. So, you can use `df[['col3']]`.

For example:

```
In [33]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
```

This gives a Series:

```
In [35]: df['a']
Out[35]: 
0    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

This gives a DataFrame:

```
In [36]: df[['a']]
Out[36]: 
   a
0  1
1  2
```

Finally, note that you can always transform a Series to a DataFrame with `reset_index`. So here, you can also use:

```
In [44]: df['a'].reset_index()
Out[44]: 
   index  a
0      0  1
1      1  2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it looks like the second on returns a pandas.core.series.Series.

Comment: @Prana Sure. Do the two remaining options (erased that one) work for you?